# Download latest version from Github, unzip to folder and overwrite contents?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Node project that's bundled and added to Github as releases.  At the moment, it checks my Github for a new release via the API and lets the user download it.  The user must then stop the Node server, unzip the release.zip to the folder and overwrite everything to update the project.

What I'm trying to do is write a Python script that I can execute in Node by spawning a new process.  This will then kill the Node server using PM2, and then Python script will then check the Github API, grab the download url, downloads it, unzips the contents to the current folder, deletes the zip and then starts up the Node server again.

What I'm struggling with though is checking the Github API and downloading the latest release file.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I've read that `wget` shouldn't be used in Python, and instead use `urlopen`

Comment: please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for ways to get data from a web server, the two main libraries are:

[Requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

[Urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html)

Personally, I prefer requests. They both have good documentation.

With requests, getting JSON data is as simple as:

```
r = requests.get("example.com")
r = r.json()
```

You can add headers and other information easily, though keep in mind that while it supports HTTP, it doesn't support HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map out your workflow and dataflow better.  You can do it in words or pictures.  If you can express your problem clearly and completely in words step by step in list format in words, then translate it to pseudocode.  Python is great because you can go almost immediately from a good written description, to pseudocode, to a working implementation.  Then at least you have something that works, and you can optimize performance, simplify functionality or usability from there.  This is the process of translating a problem into a solution.

When asking questions on SO, you need to show your current thinking, what you've already tried, preferably with your code that doesn't yet work, or work the way you need it to work.  People can vote you down and give you negative reputation points if you ask a question with just a vague description, a question that is an obvious cry for help with homework (yours is not that), or a muse or a vague question with not even an attempt at a solution, because it does not contribute back to the community in any way.

Do you have any code or detailed pseudocode steps for checking the GitHub API and checking for the "latest release" of file(s) you are trying to update?